# How to get text after <br>?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html format,

```
<tr>
    <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
        <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
            title is here 3
        </span>
        <br>
        by Ahmed 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
        <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
            title is here 2
        </span>
        <br>
        by Ahmed 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
        <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
            title is here 3
        </span>
        <br>
        by Ahmed 3
    </td>
</tr>
```

how to use jQuery to get the text after `<br>` i.e. `by Ahmed 1, by Ahmed 2, by Ahmed 3`

Comment: Updated my answer. It should now work ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var td_clone = $('.ms-vb').clone();
$('span', td_clone).remove();
alert($.trim(td_clone.text()));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Cba4m/

---

#### About your update:

```
var all_text = '';
$('.ms-vb').each(function(){
   var td_clone = $(this).clone();
   $('span', td_clone).remove();
   all_text += '' + $.trim(td_clone.text()) + '  ';
});
alert(all_text);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Cba4m/3/

Comment: It retrieves the whole text after all td with the same class. Question updated.

Answer (score 6):

```
var text = [];
$('.ms-vb').each(function() {
  text.push($(this).html().split('<br>')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
$('.ms-vb').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).html();
    var output = str.substr(str.indexOf("<br>") + 4);
    console.log(output);
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FT3Fv/2/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
jQuery('.ms-vb').html().match(/<br>([^<]*)/)[1]
```

I made a jsbin for demo purposes:

http://jsbin.com/ifufuv/11/edit

It's not currently parsing out the whitespace, but it would be trivial to add that.

Answer (score 0):

This makes a little more sense to me:

```
var text = $('.ms-vb').clone();
text.children('span').remove();
text.children('br').remove();
name = text.html()
alert(name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVHwX/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do the clone method, I would do this:

```
var result = $(".ms-vb").map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).clone().find("span").remove().end().text());
 }).get();
```

or if i were going to do the regex version, I would do this:

```
var result = $(".ms-vb").map(function() { 
    return $(this).html().match(/<br\w*\/?>\s*(.*)\s*$/)[1];
}).get();
```

Both of these will return an array of strings:

```
["by Ahmed 1", "by Ahmed 2"]
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7svj/)

*Edit:* Don't know why [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) gets no love... this is pretty much what it was made for.